# Построение нестандартного таймлайна

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Требуется построить таймлайн. Думал сделать через slick, там как раз и стрелки есть. Но не знаю как реализовать саму полосу таймлайна.

Есть ли другое решение поставленной задачи? Костылить через slick не особо хочется, особенно с учетом того, что я понятия на умею как сделать эти полоску, связывающую точки.

**Буду очень благодарен за пример кода!**

[image: таймлайн]

Comment: Это делается несколькими строками примитивного CSS. Вы бы лучше описали задачу и ограничения - может, структура HTML уже жестко задана, или как-то по-особому делать надо? Ибо если речь просто о таймлайне, то там никакой слик нафиг не нужен, как и любая другая либа.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50">
```

при клике на стрелки через **js** добавляйте/удаляйте значения в аттрибуте value.
input с типом range поддается любой css кастомизации
Слайдер тут делать ошибочно